# What is a fast way to find the necessary libraries to link against when playing around with a library

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, linker-errors, libraries

What's a good way to find the necessary libraries needed to link against when making a toy executable to play around with another library?

I'll get the appropriate compile command from the `compile_commands.json` file (generated by CMake), but I still have to manually figure out which libraries I need the executable to link to.

---

For example: if I have a file called `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <some_cool_library.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    some_cool_library::some_cool_type obj{"35"};
    return 0;
}
```

I'll grab the appropriate compile command from the `compile_commands.json` file that was generated in the project that utilized `some_cool_library.hpp` (this is so I can pass the correct `-I` flag(s) to compiler without having to think at all).

Then I'll compile it (making the appropriate compile command modifications):

```sh
/usr/bin/clang++ -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_ASIO_HAS_STD_CHRONO -DHAS_ZLIB -DWEBSOCKETPP_STRICT_MASKING -I<some-dir0> -I<some-dir1> -I<some-dir2> -isystem /usr/local/include  -Wall -Wno-invalid-partial-specialization -O3 -DNDEBUG -pthread -std=gnu++17 -o prog /home/user/main.cpp && ./prog
```

Lastly I'll get some output that spits back a bunch of linker errors where I have to manually inspect each one and link the appropriate library. Is there a better way to find these libraries?

Comment: There is no, unfortunately, a paint-by-numbers recipe to determine that. You will need to read the library's documentation which will, hopefully, explain what its dependencies are. I'm not aware of any automated tool that reads a library's external references then automatically searches the system for oter libraries that provide those symbols.

Comment: That would be a useful tool. I'll keep this question here for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to learn how to use a library is to read that library's documentation.

In some cases, [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) can be used to get the necessary compiler and linker flags. This is not guaranteed to work, but there is a reasonable chance of it working if CMake seems to automagically handle the library as a dependency.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that yesterday. If the project is a CMake project, then shouldn't there be an easy way to get the linker flags passed to the compiler for a target?